# Mongo: How to get related record if child in the same collection?

Tags: mongodb, linked-list, aggregate, aggregate-functions

A simplified example of the data structure is

```
{ _id: ObjectId, parentId: ObjectId }
```

where a parent will have `parentId` blank, and all the children will have `parentId` point to the top level record that is in the same collection.

I have an Array of ID’s that can either be a parent *or* child ID and I need to retrieve all the parent records.

So if the ID is for a parent, cool all set.

If the given ID points to a record that has a `parentId`, retrieve the record with the `_id === parentId`.

Lastly, I can't have duplicates so if I have a child ID that points to a parent record that I already have (because I was given the ID explicitly), just take the unique parent record.

so I could have a query like:

```
query: { _id: {$in: [2,3,4]}}
```

with data like

```
_id  |   parentId 
1    |   undefined
2    |   1
3    |   undefined
4    |   3
```

which should return the records for `1, 3` because `2` points to `1`, and although I have `3` and `4`, the top level is `3`.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't simply search for all the records with an undefined parentId? Wouldn't such a query return all the parent records?

Answer (score 0):

> If the given ID points to a record that has a `parentId`, retrieve the record with the `_id === parentId`.

These records can be retrieved using the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) stage of the aggregation pipeline:

```
$lookup:
     {
       from: <collection name>,
       localField: parentId,
       foreignField: _id,
       as: parentObj
     }
```

> I can't have duplicates so if I have a child ID that points to a parent record that I already have (because I was given the ID explicitly), just take the unique parent record.

The aggregation pipeline doesn't really mesh nicely with [`distinct`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/distinct/index.html). Depending on your implementation, you may be able to use the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage as a workaround, as shown by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16368638/mongodb-distinct-aggregation).