# Get sum of values from unique docs in collection of duplicate docs in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to MongoDB and I am stuck in the below scenario.

I have a collection that contains duplicate docs.
I just want to get the sum of the property in each doc excluding the duplicate docs.

My Docs looks like this:

```
{"_id":"5dd629461fc50b782479ea90",
"referenceId":"5dd581f10859d2737965d23a",
"sellingId":"319723fb80b1a297cf0803abad9bc60787537f14a6a37d6e47",
"account_name":"mrfsahas1234",
"vendor_name":"testaccount2",
"action_type":"purchase",
"product_name":"Bottle",
"product_quantity":10,
"transactionId":"319723fb80b1a297cf0803abad9bc60787537f14a6a37d6e47",
"uid":"2019-11-20T17:39:17.405Z",
"createdAt":"2019-11-21T08:56:56.589+00:00",
"updatedAt":"2019-11-21T08:56:56.589+00:00","__v":0
},
{
"_id":"5dd629461fc50b782479ea90",
"referenceId":"5dd581f10859d2737965d23a",  
"sellingId":"320a9a2f814a45e01eb98344c9af708fa2864d81587e5914",
 "account_name":"mrfsahas1234",
 "vendor_name":"testaccount2",
 "action_type":"purchase",
 "product_name":"Bottle",
 "product_quantity":50, 
 "transactionId":"320a9a2f814a45e01eb98344c9af708fa2864d81587e5914",
 "uid":"2019-11-20T17:39:17.405Z",
},
{
"_id":"5dd629461fc50b782479ea90",
"referenceId":"5dd581f10859d2737965d23a",  
"sellingId":"320a9a2f814a45e01eb98344c9af708fa2864d81587e5914",
 "account_name":"mrfsahas1234",
 "vendor_name":"testaccount2",
 "action_type":"purchase",
 "product_name":"Bottle",
 "product_quantity":50, 
 "transactionId":"320a9a2f814a45e01eb98344c9af708fa2864d81587e5914",
 "uid":"2019-11-20T17:39:17.405Z",
},
```

Currently, I am doing this:

```
MaterialsTrack.aggregate([
            {
                $match: {
                    $and: [
                        {product_name: product_name},
                        {account_name: account_name},
                        {action_type: 'purchase'},
                        {uid:uid}
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                $group: {_id: "$sellingId", PurchseQuantity: {$sum: "$product_quantity"}}
            },
        ])
```

It returns the sum of `product_quantity` all the matching docs (including the duplicate docs).
Current Output:

```
{_id: "320a9a2f814a45e01eb98344c9af708fa2864d81587e5914", PurchseQuantity:110}
```

Expected Output:

```
{_id: "320a9a2f814a45e01eb98344c9af708fa2864d81587e5914", PurchseQuantity:60}
```

I want to get the sum of only unique docs. How can I achieve it? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need  distinct values. See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16368638/mongodb-distinct-aggregation/35187100#35187100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sum inside of the $group _id field, and then use the [replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) to achieve the the result you wanted.

```
MaterialsTrack.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        {
          product_name: "Bottle"
        },
        {
          account_name: "mrfsahas1234"
        },
        {
          action_type: "purchase"
        },
        {
          uid: "2019-11-20T17:39:17.405Z"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        sellingId: "$sellingId",
        PurchaseQuantity: {
          $sum: "$product_quantity"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        _id: "$_id.sellingId",
        PurchaseQuantity: "$_id.PurchaseQuantity"
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

Sample Output:

```
[
  {
    "PurchaseQuantity": 50,
    "_id": "320a9a2f814a45e01eb98344c9af708fa2864d81587e5914"
  }
]
```

Playground:

https://mongoplayground.net/p/MOneCRiSlO0

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/NXoEdOeXSOJ - I used $group: {_id: "$sellingId", PurchseQuantity: {$addToSet : "$product_quantity"}}. And after getting result I'm accesing the data as - res['data']['PurchseQuantity'][0]

Comment: But I also liked your approach. Upvoting it!

Comment: @SaumayPaul  thank you for explanation. So the accepted answer must be edited that way. Also you can shape the result by replaceRoot without doing in the app. I think my solution is better:)

Comment: I'm not getting the perfect result. I have updated my Question. Would you mind to have a look?

Comment: @SaumayPaul can you tell how can we understand if the docs are duplicate? Which field or fields must be same to be considered duplicate?

Comment: Okay I have achieved... Updating the answer soon

Comment: and I have used your method for getting unique values

Answer (score 1):

What about adding $addToSet to your aggregations pipeline

```
MaterialsTrack.aggregate([
            {
                $match: {
                    $and: [
                        {product_name: product_name},
                        {account_name: account_name},
                        {action_type: 'purchase'},
                        {uid:uid}
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                $group: {_id: "$sellingId", PurchseQuantity: {$sum: "$product_quantity"},"list" : {$addToSet : "$list"}}
            },
        ])
```

Comment: Hey guys sorry to disturb you, but I couldn't understand how this works. In this playground it seems to return quantity 100, https://mongoplayground.net/p/nGSQK-nj8ha  Am I missing something? @SaumayPaul

Comment: $group: {_id: "$sellingId", PurchseQuantity: {$addToSet : "$product_quantity"}} is working for me

Comment: @Ahmed I have updated my Question, would you mind to have a look?

Comment: added a new Doc in Collection and Output expectation